# No space left on device: Error writing to logs/access_log

Tags: linux, log-files

Getting the following error:

```
[Wed Aug 16 00:31:23 2017] [warn] [client 128.250.0.204] (28)No space left on device: 
Error writing to logs/access_log, referer: https://...
```

The access log file seems to be filling up and not archiving. I have copied the old file and created a new one but the same thing seems to be happening.

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  38366046 Aug 17 09:19 access_log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 145557729 Aug 16 11:25 access_log.1
```

Plenty of space on the drive etc (see below)

Any advice much appreciated.

Danny.

---

```
$ sudo fdisk -l

WARNING: fdisk GPT support is currently new, and therefore in an experimental phase. Use at your own discretion.

Disk /dev/xvda: 10.7 GB, 10737418240 bytes, 20971520 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk label type: gpt


#         Start          End    Size  Type            Name
 1         4096     20971486     10G  Linux filesyste Linux
128         2048         4095      1M  BIOS boot parti BIOS Boot Partition
```

---

```
$ df -h

Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda1      9.8G  6.2G  3.5G  65% /
devtmpfs        2.0G   60K  2.0G   1% /dev
tmpfs           2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /dev/shm
/dev/xvdf        40G   11G   27G  29% /mnt/hd0
```

---

```
$ df -i

Filesystem      Inodes  IUsed   IFree IUse% Mounted on
/dev/xvda1      655360 252250  403110   39% /
devtmpfs        503768    447  503321    1% /dev
tmpfs           506002      1  506001    1% /dev/shm
/dev/xvdf      2621440 156532 2464908    6% /mnt/hd0
```

---

Services running —

```
httpd (pid  19681) is running...
ip6tables: Firewall is not running.
iptables: Firewall is not running.
irqbalance (pid  2233) is running...
lvmetad (pid  1928) is running...
lvmpolld (pid  1937) is running...
dmeventd is stopped
mdmonitor is stopped
messagebus (pid  2259) is running...
mysqld (pid  2660) is running...
netconsole module not loaded
Configured devices:
lo eth0
Currently active devices:
lo eth0
ntpd (pid  2416) is running...
Process accounting is enabled.
rdisc is stopped
rngd (pid  2242) is running...
rsyslogd (pid  2219) is running...
saslauthd is stopped
sendmail (pid  2709) is running...
sm-client (pid  2718) is running...
openssh-daemon (pid  2908) is running...
```

Comment: can you check for inodes? `df -i`

Comment: @spilla Added df -i above

Comment: xvda sounds like a virtual disk. Is it possible that the disk is thin provisioned and the disk on the host is full?

Comment: @Gerald Schneider - This is an Amazon Linux EC2 instance so I doubt it.

Comment: Can you check for any useful  message in `/var/log/messages`  or `/var/log/syslog`

Comment: @spilia nothing useful in either of those logs